# How do I check strings in a 2D array column?

Tags: java, arrays, row, indexof

I have a 2D array with a list of names and numbers. Column 1 contains all the names of people. How do I edit my function to take user input and check to see if the input matches or if the input is partially found inside one of the names in one of the string in the array?

Example:

```
Daniel Zen, 12, 3
Niel Diam, 15, 5
Arthur Ziel, 16, 99
```

My function currently takes the first column, the names, but how do I look threw each if they are matching? and how do I determine their row value.

Wanted output: (User input "IeL")

```
Daniel Zen is row 0
Niel... is row 1
Arth... is row 2
```

What I have so far takes the input, converts it to lower-case.

```
 public static void print_player_info(String[][] data, String player)
  {
   String name = player.toLowerCase();

   for(int i = 0; i<data[0].length; i++)
   {
    String namecolumn = data[i][0];
    String rownames = data[0][i];
    if(name.indexOf(namecolumn)!= -1)//i dont think this is correct
    {
   // what would need to go here
    }
   }

  }
```

Comment: rather than using 2D array, why don't you use a `list of entries` even better, if you don't have duplicate names why don't you use `Map`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something similar would do for you.. I have not tested this, have a check and let us know.

```
public static void print_player_info(String[][] data, String player) {
        String name = player.toLowerCase();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            String temp = Arrays.toString(data[i]);
            if(temp.toLowerCase().contains(player)){
                System.out.println(player + " - " + i);
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: it worked, i'll just tweak it a bit so i get the outputs i want. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void print_player_info(String[][] data, String player) {
    int i = 0;
    for (String[] dd : data) {
        for (String d : dd) {
            if (d.toLowerCase().contains(player.toLowerCase())) {
                System.out.println(d + " is row " + i);
            }

        }i++; }}
```